# how to display user's selection from option tag after a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display user's selection from option tag after click start button 
 It should display like, "You have selected 5 number follow-up questions with 3 seconds between each question". How should I do this? I don't think I should put the sentences in the div tag of displayInputVariables because it's jQuery and it's not defined yet. JavaScript reads from top to bottom.

Thank you in advance. I appreciate it.

```
<div id="container">

    <select id="numFollowUp" name="numFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Number of extra follow-up questions</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="secFollowUp" name="secFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Second between each question</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<button id="subBut" style=display:none onClick="">Start!!</button>

<div id="audioControl">
    <button id="play" style=display:none>Play!!</button>
    <button id="pause" style=display:none onClick="">Pause!!</button>
    <button id="restart" style=display:none onClick="">Restart!!</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="counDownTimer" style=display:none></div>
    <div id="displayInputVariables" style=display:none></div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#ImageEnterVariables").on("click", function() {
        $('#ImageEnterVariables').hide();
        $("#numFollowUp").show();
        $("#secFollowUp").show();
        $("#subBut").show();
        $("#pause").hide();

    });


     $(document).ready(function() {

        //start button
        $("#subBut").on("click", function() {
            $("#numFollowUp").hide();
            $("#secFollowUp").hide();
            $("#subBut").hide();
            $("#play").show();
            $("#pause").show();
            $("#restart").show();
            $("#counDownTimer").show();
            $("#displayInputVariables").show();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //start button
        $("#subBut").on("click", function() {
            $("#numFollowUp").hide();
            $("#secFollowUp").hide();
            $("#subBut").hide();
            $("#play").show();
            $("#pause").show();
            $("#restart").show();
            $("#counDownTimer").show();
            $("#displayInputVariables").show();

document.write("You have selected" + $("#numFollowUp option:selected").text() + " " + $("#numFollowUpoption[value='']").text() + " with " + $("#secFollowUp option:selected").text() + " " +$("#secFollowUp option[value='']").text());
        });
});
```

//Output should be : "You have selected 5 number follow-up questions with 3 seconds between each question" (based on values selected)

//document.write()  Write some text directly to the HTML document.

// As per your requirement, you can get the output in some div and paragraph

Comment: Thank you for replying. I just tested what you suggested but if I do this, the play, pause, restart buttons will be gone after clicking start button. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What I want is after the user clicking start, #play, $pause, #restart, and "you have selected $("#numFollowUp option:selected".) pop up on HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I did innerHTML by get Id after $("#displayInputVariables").show(); Thank you.